# Receber respostas da requisição Ajax do jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Quando eu envio um Ajax para executar o script do meu PHP a única coisa que ele retorna é success se o script foi executado com sucesso ou error se o script não foi executado com sucesso. Pergunta: Como capturar resposta do PHP e retornar esta resposta para a requisição Ajax para ela exibir ou fazer o que quiser com a mesma? Tipo:

Código jQuery enviando as variáveis e fazendo POST

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'url_especifica',   
      data: {variaveis: variaveis},
      success: function (result) {
         // Como requisitar $resposta e mostrar ela aqui
      }
      error: function (result) {
         // Como requisitar $resposta e mostrar ela aqui
      }
 });
```

Exemplo do insert PHP

```
if($Count == 0){
    $Insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_usuarios 
     VALUES ('', '$nome', '$email', '$tipo', '$senha', '$ativado', NOW())");
}
```

PHP

```
if(usuario_inserido_com_sucesso) { 
    $resposta: "O usuário foi inserido com sucesso"; }
else { 
    $resposta: "O usuário não foi inserido com sucesso"; }
```

Comment: Se fizer `echo $resposta;` no PHP depois do `if/else` o ajax vai receber e pode verificar com `alert(result);` dentro da função `success`. É isso que procura?

Comment: Vou tentar ver se dá certo assim para te responder se é isso que eu procuro. Já te retorno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar dados de um script PHP de volta para o lado do cliente tem de usar `echo`.

```
echo <conteudo>;
```

No seu caso pode usar assim no seu PHP:

```
if($Insert) $resposta = "O usuário foi inserido com sucesso";
else $resposta = "O usuário não foi inserido com sucesso";

echo $resposta;
```

(Note que mudei o seu `:` para `=`).

E no ajax pode usar assim:

```
success: function (result) {
   // usar a variavel result
   alert(result);
}
```

Comment: O resultado também pode ser uma string Json, assim você terá mais controle ao pegar via JS. Exemplo {erro:true, msg:Erro ao inserir o usuário, data:10/08/2014}

Comment: @lionbtt bom comment. `+1`

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo fazer assim:

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url_especifica',   
    data: {variaveis: variaveis},
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.substring(0,7) == 'sucesso') {
            $('#elemento').html(result.substring(8));
        } else {
            alert('ERRO: ' + result);
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
if(usuario_inserido_com_sucesso) { 
    exit("sucessoO usuário foi inserido com sucesso");
} else { 
    exit("O usuário não foi inserido com sucesso");
}
```

lembre-se que tanto o sucesso como a falha da inclusão do registro, devem ser tratados no método success, pois indica o sucesso da requisição ajax, e trata o retorno que recebeu do PHP.

Já o método error, deve ser utilizado para tratar erros na requisição ajax (timeout, error, abort, parsererror), e nesse caso ela não vai receber nenhum retorno do servidor, pois ela provavelmente não foi efetivada...