# Como recuperar via Ajax variáveis resultado de consulta no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Eu fiz uma consulta via `Ajax` que me retornou as variáveis dentro do `PHP`:

```
// Variaveis
$nome      = $Fetchi['nome'];
$email     = $Fetchi['email'];
$tipo      = $Fetchi['tipo'];
$senha     = "Digite uma nova senha...";
$ativado   = $Fetchi['ativado'];
```

Como mandar estas variáveis de volta para meu Ajax através da função success ...

```
success: function(result){
```

Só especificando, o meu sistema é um `Ajax` que faz `POST` num arquivo `PHP` que recupera estas informações através de um `SELECT` e estoca nas variáveis citadas. Quero mandar o valor destas variáveis de volta pro `Ajax` dentro da função success.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Como referí na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27580/129) precisa de usar o `echo`.

Para passar várias variàveis pode fazer um array com elas e usar o `echo`combinado com [**json_encode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
// Variaveis
$nome      = $Fetchi['nome'];
$email     = $Fetchi['email'];
$tipo      = $Fetchi['tipo'];
$senha     = "Digite uma nova senha...";
$ativado   = $Fetchi['ativado'];

$retorno = array($nome, $email, $tipo, $senha, $ativado);
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

No lado do cliente (javascript) deve usar o [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) assim:

```
success: function(result){
    var resultado = JSON.parse(result);
```

Desta maneira vai receber uma array assim:

```
[nome, email, tipo, "Digite uma nova senha...", ativado]
```

Para aceder à `senha` pode usar por exemplo `alert(resultado[3]);` se quiser ver todos os membros da array use: `alert(resultado.join('\n'));`

**Existe a possibilidade de passar um objeto também**, nalguns casos é preferivel. Assim no PHP precisa de fazer assim:

```
$retorno = array('nome'=>$nome, 'email'=>$email, 'tipo'=>$tipo, 'senha'=>$senha, 'ativao'=>$ativado);
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

No javascript usa na mesma o JSON.parse() mas vai receber um objeto neste formato:

```
{nome: 'valor do nome', email: 'valor do email', tipo: 'valor do tipo', senha: "Digite uma nova senha...", ativao: 'valor do ativao'}
```

---

Nota: Como o @jader sugeriu, use também `dataType: json` no AJAX para facilitar o parse da resposta.