# O Ajax está me retornando um array e agora, como separar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

A minha requisição Ajax está retornando 3 registros de uma consulta PHP (sim, eu tenho certeza), então temos arrays do tipo:

```
array 1 ["João", "19/05/1986", "masculino", "Programador", "Campo Grande"]
array 2 ["Maria", "15/05/1988", "feminino", "Enfermeira", "Londres"]
array 3 ["Patricia", "04/11/1980", "feminino", "Servidora Pública", "Fortaleza"]
```

Pergunta: Como separar estes dados de forma que eu possa pegar as informações de cada array separadamente e continuar meu sistema? Para ajudar vou colocar um pedaço do código

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/php_functions.php",
    data: {
        idClienteDocumentos: idClienteDocumentos,
        ajax: "true"
    },
    success: function(result) {

            var resultado = JSON.parse(result);

            // preciso montar as arrays cujo contador me confirmou que existem
            $("#Contador").val(resultado[6]);
```

Para quem se sentir a vontade para dar mais uma forcinha, preciso colocar isso dentro de um while PHP.

Comment: O que lhe dá `typeof result` e `result.length`?

Comment: Você me pegou porque ainda sou super iniciante em jQuery e não sei como obter estas informações! Pode me ajudar a saber como chego a estes dados?

Comment: Não tem problema. Faça assim: `alert('Tipo: ' + typeof resultado + ', length: ' + resultado.length);` na linha abaixo de `var resultado = JSON.parse( etc...`

Comment: Achei isso no SO en [foreach em JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Tipo: string Lenght: 83 ....

Comment: Hmmm isso depois do JSON.parse? usando `resultado` no alert?

Comment: Exatamente depois do JSON alert(resultado);

Comment: pode colocar o código que tem no php que faz echo para o ajax? algo está errado aí penso eu

Comment: Por que seu código PHP retorna um array ao invés de objetos (pessoas, imagino)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6f3q7kBC ... este é o código PHP que estou usando para buscar os resultados que estão me retornando as arrays. Esta é a imagem que tenho do alert: http://puu.sh/aEhSh/035bdea5ad.jpg ... Este é o retorno da console: http://puu.sh/aEhVN/1f0832ef96.png (tem 4 registros) que obti usando este código: http://puu.sh/aEi1V/76f478677f.png

Comment: **Daguilherme**, as vezes por falta de conhecimento me expressei mal, pode ser que ele esteja retornando objetos mesmo.

Comment: @marcosvinicius mas então fez o alert __antes__ do JSON.parse, eu escrevi "na linha abaixo". Assim está melhor

Comment: @Sergio, desculpe-me, tem razão. Acabei de arrumar e me retornou isso: http://puu.sh/aEiaC/e1bc18564c.png

Comment: Boa. Explique-me mais uma duvida: o que quer dizer com " preciso colocar isso dentro de um while PHP"?

Comment: Tenho uma tabela com arquivos inseridos relacionado a cada usuário. Então digamos que um usuário tem 5 registros de arquivos, preciso de um while para retornar os 5 registros conforme mostra a imagem: http://puu.sh/aEikI/2535685976.png

Comment: Então quer dizer algo parecido com um while do PHP mas no javascript/lado cliente?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16191/discussion-between-marcosvinicius-and-sergio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se já tem uma array a chegar depois do JSON.parse, pode usar o forEach para montar essa tabela. Se quiser fazer com divs aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
var campos = ['arquivo', 'idCliente', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'arquivo', 'data'];
var tabela = $('<div id="tabela"></div>');
resultado.forEach(function (linha) {
    var linhaDiv = $('<div></div>');
    linha.forEach(function (campo, index) {
        $('<div></div>').addClass(campos[index]).text(campo).appendTo(linhaDiv);
    });
    linhaDiv.appendTo(tabela);
});
```

Seria interessante se enviasse objetos diretamente do PHP, assim os campos que serão classes podiam vir já juntos. Eu sugiro isso no final [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27669/129).

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer o código funcionar desta forma (http://puu.sh/aEm2L/9c93ea474f.png) e não sei onde vai entrar **tabela**. Ela vai ser gerada automaticamente? No lugar aonde o script tiver posicionado? Por enquanto tenho um erro undefined no console. Além do mais quando deixo só alert, ele está dando 6 alerts que corresponde a quantidade de elementos da array e não de registros.

Comment: Como @Sergio falou, transformei em um objeto no PHP. Náo [e estranho estar retornando length: undefined? http://puu.sh/aEnP2/7fa8c5d2fe.png

Comment: @marcosvinicius estive por fora. Vi agora que teve problemas. Já consegui resolver? O exemplo que dei em cima funciona assim: http://jsfiddle.net/f32SV/

Comment: Tive problemas com `PHP` em relação ao json e tive problemas em algumas partes do script do ajax também. Tem 5 minutos que eu consegui retornar os dados. Obrigado.

Comment: @marcosvinicius ok, e agora está a funcionar? com objetos ou array?

Comment: está funcionando perfeitamente com o retorno de objetos ao ajax. obrigado pela ajuda. me adiciona no face, http://fb.com/yesmarcos e no Hangout também: mvnpereira@gmail.com ... Obrigaduuuuuuu