# buscar resultados a partir de um select

Tags: php, mysql

Eu queria a partir de um ou varios selects buscar informações da base de dados e inserir esses dados na página como texto. Isto é para ser uma "fatura".

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Código:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p></p>
<b>N&#186Marcação:</b> <input name="n_marcacao" type="number" size="1" id="n_marcacao">
<p></p>
<b>Serviço:</b>
<select name='servico' id='servico'>
<option></option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT cod_prod,nome_prod FROM produtos";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['cod_prod'].'">'.$row['nome_prod'].'</option>';
    }

?>
</select>
<br>
<p></p>
<b>Nome do Cliente:</b>
<select name='cod_cli'>
<option></option>
<?php
       $sql = "SELECT cod_cli,nome_cli FROM dados_cli";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['cod_cli'].'">'.$row['nome_cli'].'</option>';
       }
    ?>
</select>
<br>
<p></p>
<b>Compareceu:</b>
<select name='compareceu' id='selecionar'>
<option>Selecionar a opção</option>
<option data-section="comp" value='1'>Compareceu</option>
<option value='0'>Não Compareceu</option>
</select><br>
<!--Se compareceu-->
<div data-name="comp" class ="hide">
<p></p>
<b>Usou Voucher:</b>
<select id="select" name="servico_com_voucher">
<option>Selecionar</option>
<option data-sections="usou" value="1">Usou</option>
<option value="0">Não Usou</option>
</select><br>
</div>
<!--Se usou Voucher-->
<div data-names="usou" class="hide2">
<p></p>
<b>C&oacutedigo do Voucher:</b>
<select name='cod_voucher' id='voucher'>
<option>Selecionar Voucher</option>
<?php 

       $sql = "SELECT cod_voucher FROM vouchers";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['cod_voucher'].'"> '.$row['cod_voucher'].' </option>';
       }
    ?>
</select><br>
</div>
<p></p>
<input name="inserir" type="submit" id="inserir" class="button" value="Inserir venda"/>
</form>
<b>Preço:</b> <?php 
    $cod_prod=isset($_POST['servico']);
    $sql = "SELECT preco FROM produtos WHERE cod_prod LIKE '%".$cod_prod."%'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($ligacao));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    $valor_prod=number_format($row['preco'],2,","," ")."€";
    echo $valor_prod;
    ?>
<br>
<b>Desconto:</b> <?php
    $cod_voucher=isset($_POST['cod_voucher']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vouchers INNER JOIN produtos ON vouchers.cod_prod=produtos.cod_prod WHERE cod_voucher LIKE '%".$cod_voucher."%'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($ligacao));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    if($row['tipo']==1){
        $valor_fix=number_format($row['valor'],2,","," ")."€";
        echo $valor_fix;
    }elseif($row['tipo']==2){
        $perc=$row['valor']*100;
        echo $perc."%";
    }elseif($row['tipo']==3){
        echo "Oferta: ".$row['nome_prod'];
    }
?><br>
<b>Total da Venda:</b> <?php
    if($row['tipo']==1){
        $valor_total=$valor_prod+$valor_fix;
        echo number_format($valor_total,2,","," ")."€";
    }elseif($row['tipo']==2){
        $valor_perc=$perc/100;
        $valor_total=$valor_prod*$valor_perc;
    }elseif($row['tipo']==3){
        echo "Oferta";
    }
?>
```

Tabelas usadas: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EOax.jpg

Comment: Sabemos o que quer, e como você tentou, mas que problema você teve? Algum erro? Dúvidas com relação a qualidade do código?

Comment: o texto ja veio assim por defeito não altera eu queria que altera se quando indico outro opção do select

Comment: Que texto? O que é alterado? O que deveria acontecer quando é alterado? O que está acontecendo? Tente ser o mais claro e específico possível

Comment: Estas a ver onde diz 
Preço:...
Desconto:...
Total da Venda:....    Queria alterar quando mudo a opção muda os valores de cada texto

Comment: Por exemplo mudasse o serviço mudava o preço em baixo e mudava o total. Se mudar o codigo do voucher mudo o desconto se nao usou voucher fica com o preço normal

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como recuperar via Ajax variáveis resultado de consulta no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27668/) Essa é só um exemplo, se procurar pelos termos PHP e AJAX, achará diversas perguntas semelhantes

Comment: Não responde a minha pergunta

Comment: Imagine que selecionei outro serviço e outro voucher os textos não mudam de números.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105392/discussion-between-bruno-teixeira-and-costamilam).